# Regarding map::erase and map::count

Tags: c++, string, dictionary

I simply have a quick question regarding the use of map::count() and map::erase(). I am using these with a std::string, but would like to know if I need to use string::c_str(). For example, my code currently appears as this:

```
void Person::removeFriend(std::string first, std::string last){
    std::string name = (first + last);
    //checks to ensure the friend exists in the user's friend list
    if (_friends.count(name) == 1){
        _friends.erase(name);
    }
}
```

So my question then is, should it actually appear as this:

```
void Person::removeFriend(std::string first, std::string last){
    std::string name = (first + last);
    //checks to ensure the friend exists in the user's friend list
    if (_friends.count(name.c_str()) == 1){
        _friends.erase(name.c_str());
    }
}
```

Also, I suppose this would also apply to map::insert() as well. I only know this usage from opening files with std::string. Any and all advice is greatly appreciated in advance!

Comment: The only reason `c_str` was needed with file streams was because they used to only take `const char*`, and wouldn't compile if given a `std::string`.

Comment: @chris so, in other words, you are saying that these functions do not require the same params and would therefore compile fine without the use of `c_str`?

Comment: Assuming your `std::map` keys are defined as `std::string` to begin with, then yes, you can pass `std::string` values to `count()` and `erase()`. BTW, using `count()` is not the best way to test for existence, you can use `find()` instead. It returns an `iterator` to the first matching key, and then you can `erase()` that specific item using that iterator. If you `erase()` by key value, the key has to be searched for again, which you already found beforehand so the second search is redundant and potentially wasteful, depending on how many items are in the map.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, my `map` keys are `std::string`. I will change `count()` to `find()`, thanks for the advice. Is there a particular reason `find()` is better? EDIT: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: What is the type of `_friends`?

Comment: @RSahu `_friends` is of type `map<std::string, Person>`, where `Person` is a class I have defined.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd bother with `count` or `find`. If you want to erase if it's there and nothing else, just `erase`.

Comment: @FredLarson I suppose that's a valid point. It does not throw an error if the key does not exist?

Comment: What Fred means is if you `erase()` by key value, it will remove the item if found, otherwise it will not remove anything and it will not throw an error.  That version of `erase()` returns how many items were actually removed. Thus, `count(name)` and `iter = find(name); erase(iter);` are both redundant when using `erase(name)` by itself.

Comment: fyi - c_str is a std::string method, so you would have needed to use 'name.c_str()'

Comment: @CreasyBear, FYI, there's generally [great documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) for all of the standard library.

Comment: @chris, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no reason to use `c_str` here. And you don't need to check for existence before using `erase`. Your function could be simply this:

```
void Person::removeFriend(const std::string& first, const std::string& last){
    std::string name = (first + last);
    _friends.erase(name);
}
```

... or even:

```
void Person::removeFriend(const std::string& first, const std::string& last){
    _friends.erase(first + last);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::map` has an overload of [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) that takes just the key.

```
size_type erase( const key_type& key );
```

You can simply use:

```
std::string name = (first + last);
_friends.erase(name);
```